# URL not working with encoding - error 404 found

Tags: php, .htaccess, urlencode, urldecode

When i try to access the encoded url

decoded: [https://downloaderapk.site/µtorrent-remote](https://downloaderapk.site/%C2%B5torrent-remote)

encoded:https://downloaderapk.site/%C2%B5torrent-remote

I got

> 404 Error. Page Not Found.

my `.htaccess` rewrite rule is as

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ app.php?&slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/$ app.php?&slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

I think i am forgetting the rewrite rule?

Comment: AFAIK URLs can only contain ASCII values.

Comment: Well, what "slug" is handed over to your script? Only you can tell.

Answer (score 0):

The regex patterns in your rewrite rules are excluding the % used for encoding the non-ASCII characters.

Replace them with

```
^(.+)$
```

Comment: The URL has already been decoded at this point. The rule pattern does not get applied to `%C2%B5torrent-remote` here, but to `µtorrent-remote`. `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]` of course doesn’t match the `µ` character, but _not_ because of an issue with `%`.

Comment: Please tell exactly what i have to write my rewrite rule? Thank